# How can Add new line in plist

Tags: objective-c, plist

Hi friends i'm beginner
and sorry for simple Questions.

how can i add new lines in ""plist"" for saving data
and access keys in it.

```
NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hello",nil];
[values writeToFile:[self PathArray] atomically:YES];
```

because , this method Only overwrite Values in ([self PathArray]) "path";

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plist files are not designed for incremental updates, instead you should load plist contents in memory, add an item to it and save back:

```
NSMutableArray *oldValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self PathArray]];
NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hello",nil];
[oldValues addObjectsFromArray:values];    
[oldValues writeToFile:[self PathArray] atomically:YES];
[values release]; // Do not forget this line to avoid memory leak
```

Comment: hi, i know this was answer for almost a yr now. i tried this method and it does not work. it is not writing into the plist. or does it even write it into the plist permanently?

Comment: @MelvinLai, it should work. Two possible problems - your're trying to write to a invalid path (or where you don't have writing permissions),  or your array contains non-plist objects (plist objects are NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSNumber...)

Comment: the path is correct, i can read the plist successfully but cannot write on it. regarding to the permissions, where do i set it? at the get info when right clicked? and i am using nsstring to write into the plist, is there a way to check if the plist is successfully updated?

Comment: @Melvin to what directory do you want to write it? writeToFile returns bool value indicating if write operation succeeded

Comment: to my documentsDirectory, i try to set a bool variable and see if its returning true rather than false then. my question would be the same as the topic. **EDIT:** yes it is a successful writeToFile, but when i go to the temp files? at the documents directory, my plist does not show an updated data.

Comment: @Melvin it is hard to tell without seeing actual code. Try to recheck everything mentioned above, if nothing helps it may be worth to start new question and post your code there so more people will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

In my item, the dictionary data includes null, for example :

```
{
 "category_id" = 29;
   "category_name" = "\U5f69\U6f2b";
   coverurl = "<null>";
   position = 29;
}
```

so `writetofile`, return value always FALSE.